# Problema en Formulario con input por GET en PHP no agrega '&' al Header

Tags: php, html, formularios

Tengo un .htaccess que tiene esta linea:

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2

Y tengo un fichero que se llama loadController por el que pasan en cada peticion concatenando de la siguiente manera:

```
$controllerDefine = isset($_GET['controller']);
if ($controllerDefine) $controllerName = $_GET['controller'] . 'Controller';


$actionDefine = isset($_GET['action']);
if ($actionDefine)  $action = $_GET['action'];
```

Esto lo que haces es reescribir la URL para que sea amigable entonces yo poder escribir los url asi:

localhost/MiPagina/MiControlador/MiAccion

Por lo tanto mi primer parametro por GET es el controller.

El problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un form para un filtro de title en un listado de productos, que para poder concatenar otros filtro como por categoria necesito que sea por POST para despues poder mantener el filtro.
El problema es que cuando hago el submit la URL que arma la hace asi:

-http://localhost/EGXD/product/all?search=H

Cuando para que pueda tomar el valor de GET en el BACKEND tiene qe ser asi:

http://localhost/EGXD/product/all&search=H

La diferencia es que en vez de poner el '&' Pone '?' por lo tanto no toma en el $_GET["search"]. PERO EL PRIMER PARAMETRO ES 'controller' y ese es el que lleva '?', por lo tanto este no lo puede tomar por '?' si no que tiene qe agregarse como '&'.

Dejo el codigo :

```
<form action="<?php echo URL_BASE . "product/all" . $filtercategory . $filtersort . $filterpage ?>" method="GET">
       <div class="input-group col-xl-11 m-3 aling-self-start">
           <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="button-addon1">Buscar</button>
           </div>
           <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="form-control col" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
       </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Cuando usas el método GET, no se agregan las variables que pones en la URL, necesitas crear campos ocultos `<input type="hidden" ..>` para cada una.

Answer (score 0):

D J C:

El que te devuelva un '?' es porque estás utilizando la variable $_GET esto lo que hace lo denominado "Query string", forma parte de la "búsqueda" que hace.

Si cambiaras, por ejemplo, tu línea del form action a:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
```

El resultado sería:

```
?search=cadenaInsertadaFormulario
```

Si añadiera un segundo input, por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="segundoParametro" value="test"/>
```

El resultado de llenar los dos campos y hacer un submit sería:

```
... ?search=cadenaInsertadaFormulario1&segundoParametro=cadenaInsertadaFormulario2
```

Podrías editar la pregunta y colocar un poco más de información para entender el porqué necesitas la URL de esa forma. Saludos.

Comment: Editado. Gracias

Comment: Hola @D J C, ¿algún avance con tu pregunta?

Comment: Si, el problema era el htaccess. Como es un framework personalizado, estaba tomando como primer parametro el controller. Gracias

Comment: Genial, D J C, me alegro hayas podido solucionarlo. ¡Saludos!